# Magento enable shipping method for virtual products

Tags: magento-1.9, php, shipping-methods, table-rates, virtual-products

Hello we are using magento 1.9.2 and we have only virtual products. I want to apply shipping method for the virtual products which is not there in magento. Please help me in adding the shipping method to the virtual products.

Also I want the shipping rates should be configured in terms of distance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virtual products cannot have a shipping method, as they are intended to represent non-physical items such as a warranty or a membership.

To achieve what you are describing, you would need to use a different product type such as simple products along with the default tablerates shipping, or if you needed a more complex setup perhaps WebshopApps MatrixRates or ProductMatrix to provide the different rates.

This would allow you to both specify the shipping method, and give you control over different rates to different areas and countries.

**Note: I am not affiliated with Webshopapps in any way**